# Reading data from .raw file

Tags: c++, image

I have RAW file in grayscale with 8-bit data and I'm trying to read the data using simple program:

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    char fileName[80] = "TEST.raw";
    //char buffer[255];
    ifstream fin(fileName);
    char ch;
    int i = 0;
    while (fin.get(ch)){
        cout << (unsigned int)ch << " ";
        i++;
    }
    cout << endl;
    cout << "i = " << i;
    fin.close();
    cin >> ch;
}
```

Some of values are higher than some specific value and I'm getting strange output. When i should get something like this:

```
(...) 34    34    34    36    43    59    88    123    151    166 (...)
```

i have:

```
(...) 34 34 34 36 43 59 88 123 4294967191 4294967206 (...)
```

I guess it's simple problem, but I have no idea how to do it correctly.

Comment: get returns an int. Don't convert to char, and then to unsigned.

Comment: You shouldn't be using fixed-size arrays for constant strings. What does `80` mean here? Nothing. Why not `const char* fileName = "TEST.raw";` instead?

Comment: tadman, you're sure. Thanks for this tip.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your `ch` variable declaration to

```
   unsigned char ch;
// ^^^^^^^^
```

and as recommended in the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get) change `fin.get(ch)` to

```
while (fin >> ch)
```

to fix this behavior.

`char` values need to be explicitly being `signed` or `unsigned`, when you use them as integer numerics. So if a value is bigger than 126 it's interpreted as a negative number. Negative numbers casted to `unsigned int` will set the high bits of those values.

Comment: I was trying it, but for now I have an error:

1>d:\programowanie\czytanieraw\czytanieraw\czytanieraw\source.cpp(11): error C2664: 'std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>> &std::basic_istream<char,std::char_traits<char>>::get(std::basic_streambuf<char,std::char_traits<char>> &,_Elem)' : cannot convert argument 1 from 'unsigned char' to 'char &'

1>          with

1>          [
1>              _Elem=char
1>          ]
1>d:\programowanie\czytanieraw\czytanieraw\czytanieraw\source.cpp(11): fatal error C1903: unable to recover from previous error(s); stopping compilation

Comment: BTW, the type `char` can be implemented by the compiler as `signed`, `unsigned` or `char`.  There is no default value, it is implementation specific.

Comment: @Adek I have updated my answer. You can also get this hint from the [documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/get).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews you are correct, it's implementation defined. But are you aware of any implementations that *don't* use signed?

Comment: Yes, embedded systems.  I currently have my embedded system environment set up for a default setting of `unsigned` character.  The big issue is when the static analysis tools are set up differently than the compiler.

Comment: Uh, my program for now is working, but I've found different mistake. My `i` variable says that I have 31851 values in 160x200 .raw image. Missing 149 values is number of 32s, what is 'space' in ASCII. Don't ask how I've found it ;)

Comment: @Adek are you sure the missing values are 32 and not 13?

Comment: @MarkRansom Yep, I'm sure. I've checked it and for now solved it by using `noskipws` in `while (fin >> noskipws >> ch)`.